# Handling background operation for countdown/chronometer

Tags: android

I've been doing a bit of research but I'm currently still not sure what particular class I should use to handle this situation.

I'm implementing an app with an activity with a countdown timer and a chronometer, both of which are intended to be run for a long period of time (>1 hour). I want both of them to keep running when the app is currently not in the foreground (for example, the user clicked the home button and will return to the app after >20 minutes). Once the user goes back to the app, the activity in which he pressed the home button should be the one that shows up and both the chronometer and countdown timer should continue to run.

Based on my research I have the following options:

- Service
- Handler
- AsyncTask

However, with Service there is the possibility that it can be terminated when the system is low on memory. For Handler, it doesn't appear to be suitable for operations persisting for long period of time, the same goes to AsyncTask. What are some other classes I should look into to resolve this? Or would one of these three be sufficient? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could try starting a foreground service.

Comment: Thanks looks like that's the way to go, feel free to post this as an answer!